# "Object of class App\User could not be converted to int" error in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to save new user with Ajax request in Laravel and i'm getting the following error,

```
Object of class App\User could not be converted to int
```

I must add the the user is saved, so i'm not sure from where this error comes.

Here is the UserController:

```
public function save_user(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            if (request()->ajax()) {
                $lastUserId = User::where('user_id', '>', 0)->orderBy('user_id', 'desc')->get('user_id')->first()->toArray();

                $user = new User;
                $data = Input::all();
                $user->user_id = intval($lastUserId['user_id'] + 1);
                $user->user_type = $data['user_type'];
                $user->email = $data['email'];
                $user->password = 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e';
                $user->first_name = $data['first_name'];
                $user->last_name = $data['last_name'];

                $user->save();
                if ($user > 0) {
                    return response()->json('Success');
                }
                return response()->json(['status' => 200, 'message' => 'save success']);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Here is the Ajax request:

```
$('#saveUser').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $inputs = $('#new-user-form :input');

            var values = {};
            $inputs.each(function () {
                if (this.name != '_token' && this.name.length > 0) {
                    values[this.name] = $(this).val();
                }

            });

            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/save_user',
                type: "post",
                data: values,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    /// location.reload();
                }
            });

        })
```

Here is the User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Detail;
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\User'); //Product Model Name
    }
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I've tried to convert all the input values to their type - like in the DB but it didn't worked

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make a new user ? if so then why don't you just make your user_id something like `$table->increments('user_id');` so it will auto increments user_id every time you create a new user and you can remove `$user->user_id = intval($lastUserId['user_id'] + 1);`

Comment: AH.Pooladvand, thanks - now i'm getting "Call to undefined method App\User::increments()"

Comment: Can you post your `users` table

Comment: Yes, i've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

In your condition, you are trying to see if a `collection` of user is `> 0`, and because of that, you're getting the error above, since Laravel is trying to parse the `collection` of user to `int` datatype, to make it countable. Refactor your condition to this:

```
if (count($user) > 0) {
  return response()->json('Success');
}
```

or another way:

```
if ($user) {
  return response()->json('Success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this in your controller

```
if ($user > 0) {
   return response()->json('Success');
}
```

To this

```
if ($user) {
   return response()->json('Success');
}
```